# htaccess change url strings to simple slug

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

**This is my current url**

```
https://www.example.com/content.php?q=1&s=title-sample-slug
```

**I need to change above url using this type url**

```
https://www.example.com/title-sample-slug
```

how can i do it using htaccess file. Need to hide the `content.php?q=1&s=` from url in the browser.

Comment: You are parsing the variables via GET. Try using POST instead. This have nothing to do with the htaccess file but I would recommend it to solve this problem.

Comment: no you get it wrong :)  im genarating post using for each loop so i need to view a every single post using https://www.example.com/title-sample-slug this but actual url will be https://www.example.com/content.php?q=1&s=title-sample-slug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is correct answer for my question**

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} q=([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)&s=([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) 
RewriteRule content.php %2 [L,QSD]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} q=1&s=(.+) 
RewriteRule content.php %1 [L]
```

Comment: not working :(  i need to rewrite url thats all https://www.example.com/content.php?q=1&s=title-sample-slug  to https://www.example.com/title-sample-slug :(

Comment: still getting :( anyway thanx for trying to help me :)

Comment: with  RewriteRule content.php %1 [L,QSD] it works for me : the new url is :80/title-sample-slug

Comment: actually it's working but when we change the (q= value) getting an error so the parameter needs to be dynamic how can I do that